Cusp forms on $\text{GL}_1(D)$
I am reading the book Zeta Functions of Simple Algebras by Godement and Jacquet.
Let $F$ be a global field, $D$ a central divisible algebra over $F$ of dimension $d^2$ and $G=\text{GL}_m(D)$. Set $n=md$.
In chap.10, the define the space of automorphic forms and cusp forms $G$.
In particular, for $m=1$, they define the space of cusp forms with central character $\omega$ (no need to be unitary) as the subspace of $\varphi$ in the space of automorphic forms with central character $\omega$ such that the following integral vanishes:
$$\int_{G(F)Z(A)\backslash G(\mathbb{A})}\varphi(g)\omega'(\nu(g^{-1}))\mathrm{d}g$$
where $\nu$ is the reduced norm of $M_m(D)$ and $\omega'$ is a character of $F^\times\backslash\mathbb{A}^\times$ such that $\omega'^n=\omega$.
For example, when $n=m=d=1$, $G=\mathbb{G}_m$, and $\omega$ is the trivial character, by definition the constant function $1$ is not a cusp form.
We may assume $d=1$ from now on. My question is that, will there be problem if we use this definition to do one of the following processes:

Getting all irreducible automorphic representations of $\text{GL}_n$ by all irreducible subquotient of parabolic induction of cuspidal representations.
Getting all automorphic forms on $\text{GL}_n$ by all Taylor series of cuspidal Eisenstein series.

In both cases, we will consider cuspidal representations of the levi component of a parabolic subgroup. And the levi component is of the form $\text{GL}_{n_1}\times \text{GL}_{n_2}\times\dots \text{GL}_{n_m}$. When some $n_i$ equals to one we meet the problem.

What is parabolic induction for $D^\times$?  And what are cuspidal Eisenstein series?
